# How to get Chrome webdriver to scrape salary value and not "Glassdoor est"

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

The output of the `salary_estimate` variable is '$39K-$72K (Glassdoor est.)'
The goal is to retrieve salary value such as '$39K-$72K' and not including '(Glassdoor est.)'

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path="C:/webdrivers/chromedriver", options=options)
url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/data-scientist-jobs-SRCH_KO0,14_IP2.htm'
driver.get(url)
salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath('.//span[@class="css-1uyte9r css-hca4ks e1wijj242"]').text
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get rid of the child nodes you don't want. And you can do that executing a javascript with your driver.

Append this to your code:

```py
salary = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].firstChild.textContent;', salary_estimate).strip()
print(salary)
```

This will ensure you get only the first element text.

Comment: I tried your code but I got an error saying "JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
  (Session info: chrome=87.0.4280.88)"

Comment: I forgot to mention, but did you remove `.text` from `salary_estimate = driver.find_element_by_xpath(...).text` ? Because you need to pass the element, not the text